# TronWeb: mnemonics or private key?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, tron, tronweb

I have a few beginner's questions to you:

1. Why do we need mnemonics if all accounts are restored on instantination of tron web instance through passing the private key?
2. What is 0th account which is returned after the tronWeb.createRandom() is called?

I tried looking on the internet, but I'm stuck with this for quite a while..